# Putting tick marks on graph without label using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, graphs

I'm trying to create a piecewise function on a colored background with Ti*k*Z that has tick marks on the coordinate axes every 2 units but a grid that intersects the axes every 1 unit. The problem I have is that when I try to add blank spaces for the labels for the tick marks I don't want to show up on the grid, the color background of the blank label cuts off the grid line.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}} 
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{ExampleFrame}{%
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
leftline=false,
rightline=false,
innertopmargin=20pt,
innerbottommargin=20pt,
innerrightmargin=20pt,
innerleftmargin=20pt,
backgroundcolor=blue!5!white}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=ExampleFrame]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
 axis lines=middle,
 ticklabel style={fill=blue!5!white},
 xmin=-6.5,xmax=6.5,
 xtick={-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6},xticklabels={-6, ,-4, ,-2, , ,2, ,4, ,6},
 ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
 ytick={-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4},yticklabels={-4, ,-2, , ,2, ,4},
 xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
 samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-6:-2,thick] {x+3};
\addplot[domain=-2:1,thick] {2*x+2};
\addplot[domain=1:3,thick] {-2*x+6};
\addplot[domain=3:4,thick] {-4*x+15};
\addplot[domain=4:6,thick] {-1};

\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(-2,1)(3,3)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(-6,-3)(-2,-2)(3,0)(6,-1)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this.

[image: output]

How do I fix the blank labels so they don't block the grid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply give only the tick points you want to have a label and make the remaining ones as `minor tick` so that you don't need to skip the labels that you don't want to have.

One details is that if you have a color spec with the missing second argument such as `blue!10` then `white` is automatically assumed.

Also 200 samples for lines are overkill.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
             holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
             compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
 axis lines=middle,
 ticklabel style={fill=blue!5!white},
 xmin=-6.5,xmax=6.5,
 ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,
 xtick={-6,-4,-2,2,4,6},     %<--
 ytick={-4,-2,2,4},          %<--
 minor tick = {-5,-3,...,5}, %<--
 xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
 samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-6:-2,thick] {x+3};
\addplot[domain=-2:1,thick] {2*x+2};
\addplot[domain=1:3,thick] {-2*x+6};
\addplot[domain=3:4,thick] {-4*x+15};
\addplot[domain=4:6,thick] {-1};
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(-2,1)(3,3)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(-6,-3)(-2,-2)(3,0)(6,-1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, 200 points per line is overkill by factor 100.

Comment: The 200 points per line was leftover from copying and pasting from other nonlinear functions in the document, but I'll change it for the lines. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 0.87} % scaling to avoid `overfull \hbox` warning
\begin{pspicture}(-6.4,-4.5)(6.92,4.95) % boundry found manually
  % coordinate grid
  \psaxes[
    labels = none,
    tickcolor = gray!50,
    tickwidth = 0.5pt,
    xticksize = -4 4,
    yticksize = -6 6
  ]{->}(0,0)(-6.4,-4.5)(6.5,4.5)
  % axes
  \psaxes[
    Dx = 2,
    Dy = 2
  ]{->}(0,0)(-6.4,-4.5)(6.5,4.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  % data points and line segments
  \psline{*-o}(-6,-3)(-2,1)
  \psline{*-*}(-2,-2)(1,4)(3,0)
  \psline{o-*}(3,3)(4,-1)(6,-1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]